# Parse Android Blank Project Error

Tags: parse-platform

I downloaded the Android Blank Project (v.1.11.0) from the website: https://parse.com/docs/downloads

And when I loaded the project using build.gradle to Android Studio, I got error saying Gradle project sync failed, after hitting the "Try Again" link, I got the following error:

**Error:Failed to find: com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0**
Open File
Open in Project Structure dialog

**Error:Failed to find: com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0**
Open File
Open in Project Structure dialog

Initially there were more failed to find error like this, but after "Try Again", only these two remained.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
}
```

I have tried modifying the dependencies to "com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.+", but I still couldn't find anything.

I am just starting, please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. In Android Studio create a new project
2. Add this code to build.gradle and then sync your project

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
       compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
   }
   ```
3. Add this code to AndroidManifest.xml before the `<application>` tag

   ```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   ```
4. Add this to onCreate() method in your activity:

   ```
   // Enable Local Datastore.
   Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
   Parse.initialize(this, "APPLICATION_KEY", "CLIENT_KEY");
   ```

   You can find your codes here: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing
   or by going to Parse>Your App>Docs>QuickStart
5. Add this code after calling initialize:

   ```
   ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
   testObject.put("foo", "bar");
   testObject.saveInBackground();
   ```
6. Run the code and then press the "Test" button on the webpage from step 4

It should work. If you have any problems or questions just leave a comment and I will try to help you! :)

Comment: Hi @gregory, I did everything you mentioned, but it still didn't work. Seems like my Android studio cannot find com.parse, however it finds com.android just fine. Do you know what could have caused this issue?

Comment: What error does it give you and what options? Also please update the questions with the entire build.gradle file

Comment: I actually resolved this issue myself just now. I had to download the sdk locally to a libs folder, and specify dependencies to them. Thanks thouh! ^_^